# How to link library in C/c++ project in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu

I tried to install libantlr3c-3.4. When I ran sudo make install, it installed it successfully and gave the following output:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libantlr3c.so /opt/open64/lib/libantlr3c.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libantlr3c.lai /opt/open64/lib/libantlr3c.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libantlr3c.a /opt/open64/lib/libantlr3c.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /opt/open64/lib/libantlr3c.a
libtool: install: ranlib /opt/open64/lib/libantlr3c.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /opt/open64/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /opt/open64/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

After which I run make on another project which gives me the following error:

```
 fatal error: antlr3.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried to paste the path /opt/open64/lib in /etc/ld.so.conf which then contained the following information:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
include /opt/open64/lib
```

I again ran make and again got the same error.

I am a newbie to C and am new to setting library paths. Can someone please guide me as to how should I make my project.

The procedure which I used for installing libantlr3c-3.4 is:

```
tar -xzvf libantlr3c-3.4.tar.gz
./configure
make 
make install
```

Comment: The error is related to the fact the compiler cannot find the `antlr3.h` header file and so compilation fails, you haven't even got to the link step yet. You need to set up your include paths for your project.

Comment: I think you should install some devel pack (maybe there is option to `make devel` ?), or manually find the include file and add its dir as include dir (-I)

Comment: @sjdowling How do i set up link path for the project. Can you please help with this a bit.

Comment: @SHR Sorry but I did not get as to where should I include dir(-l). I tried make dir(-l) but it did not work

Comment: @JannatArora In the makefile you failed to build. it is depend how you created the makefile. for example: if you used `cmake` then look at cmake tutorial for include_directories, You can always add it manually to the makefile under CPP_FLAGS...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know where the .h is. When you compile, you have to tell it where to look. From command line:

```
   gcc -I path_to_where_h_file_lives myFile.cpp
```